# Validate at least one element sharing the same class

Tags: javascript, html, class, validation, element

I am trying to create a function that grabs all elements with the same one class and validates that AT LEAST ONE of those elements is filled in.

I am wanting it to check for any element with the class of "rowvalidate" and ensure that at least one of the elements with that class is filled out entirely before allowing form submission. If someone decides to fill out multiple of these elements each element must be filled out completely.

Sorry if this question is poorly written, I am still new to posting on here. If you need more information let me know.

Below is my javascript, which I believe to be very incorrect:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("rowvalidate");
  for (i > 0; i++) {
    if (!myForm.rows.value.length) {
      valid = false;
      document.getElementById('row-error').style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('row-error').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<table>
  <span class="form-error" id="row-error">At least one persons info must be entered</span>
    <tr class="rowvalidate">
        <th>1</th>
        <td>
            <label for="bfname1">Firstname</label>
            <input type="text" id="bfname1" name="firstname1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="bsname1">Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" id="bsname1" name="surname1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="borank1">Officer Rank</label>
            <input type="text" id="borank1" name="officerrank1">
        </td>
        <td class="form-element">
            <label for="badge">Choose a Badge Type (A, B, or C)</label>
            <select name="badge" class="badge">
                <option value="" selected>Select Badge</option>
                <option value="7.50">A</option>
                <option value="8.00">B</option>
                <option value="10.00">C</option>
            </select>
            - $ <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="price">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowvalidate">
        <th>2</th>
        <td>
            <label for="bfname2">Firstname</label>
            <input type="text" id="bfname2" name="firstname2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="bsname2">Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" id="bsname2" name="surname2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="borank2">Officer Rank</label>
            <input type="text" id="borank2" name="officerrank2">
        </td>
        <td class="form-element">
            <label for="badge">Choose a Badge Type (A, B, or C)</label>
            <select name="badge" class="badge">
                <option value="" selected>Select Badge</option>
                <option value="7.50">A</option>
                <option value="8.00">B</option>
                <option value="10.00">C</option>
            </select>
            - $ <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="price">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowvalidate">
        <th>3</th>
        <td>
            <label for="bfname3">Firstname</label>
            <input type="text" id="bfname3" name="firstname3">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="bsname3">Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" id="bsname3" name="surname3">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="borank3">Officer Rank</label>
            <input type="text" id="borank3" name="officerrank3">
        </td>
        <td class="form-element">
            <label for="badge">Choose a Badge Type (A, B, or C)</label>
            <select name="badge" class="badge">
                <option value="" selected>Select Badge</option>
                <option value="7.50">A</option>
                <option value="8.00">B</option>
                <option value="10.00">C</option>
            </select>
            - $ <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="price">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowvalidate">
        <th>4</th>
        <td>
            <label for="bfname4">Firstname</label>
            <input type="text" id="bfname4" name="firstname4">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="bsname4">Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" id="bsname4" name="surname4">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="borank4">Officer Rank</label>
            <input type="text" id="borank4" name="officerrank4">
        </td>
        <td class="form-element">
            <label for="badge">Choose a Badge Type (A, B, or C)</label>
            <select name="badge" class="badge">
                <option value="" selected>Select Badge</option>
                <option value="7.50">A</option>
                <option value="8.00">B</option>
                <option value="10.00">C</option>
            </select>
            - $ <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="price">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowvalidate">
        <th>5</th>
        <td>
            <label for="bfname5">Firstname</label>
            <input type="text" id="bfname5" name="firstname5">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="bsname5">Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" id="bsname5" name="surname5">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="borank5">Officer Rank</label>
            <input type="text" id="borank5" name="officerrank5">
        </td>
        <td class="form-element">
            <label for="badge3">Choose a Badge Type (A, B, or C)</label>
            <select name="badge" class="badge">
                <option value="" selected>Select Badge</option>
                <option value="7.50">A</option>
                <option value="8.00">B</option>
                <option value="10.00">C</option>
            </select>
            - $ <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="price">
        </td>
</table>
```

Thanks =)

Comment: "Filled out completely", is there a minimum character or something? What is "completely" meaning? Just at least one letter?

Comment: I mean all the inputs and select function within each (tr class="rowvalidate")

Comment: There are 5 tr elements with the class rowvalidate. I want the function to make at least one of those tr elements required that meaning all inputs within that element are required

Comment: Hi iHamishio and welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you written any code to validate an individual row that you can share, and when does row validation take place? Also span elements are not permitted child elements of a table (see under [**permitted content**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). You should move the `row-error` span in HTML so it isn't the child of a table - although browsers might move it outside the table for you, in the worst case they may not display it at all.

Comment: I have moved the span element outside the table as suggested. Apart form the javascript and HTML I have already sent there is no other code I have written for this, as I am not really sure where to even start.

Comment: The validation takes place further down the HTML within the input submit:
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: Heres the question if it helps:                                                                                  
There must be 1 or more badges (up to maximum of 5) for the form to be valid, Each badge must have all details completed. There cannot be partially filled out badge information (First
name, surname, Officer Rank, and badge option are required for each badge)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your HTML, I added a class `empty` per default to all `input`, please read the entire post to know the logic behind it.

```
<body>
    <table>
        <span class="form-error" id="row-error">At least one persons info must be entered</span>
        <tr class="rowvalidate">
            <th>1</th>
            <td>
                <label for="bfname1">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" id="bfname1" name="firstname1" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="bsname1">Lastname</label>
                <input type="text" id="bsname1" name="surname1" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="borank1">Officer Rank</label>
                <input type="text" id="borank1" name="officerrank1" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td class="form-element">
                <label for="badge">Choose a Badge Type (A, B, or C)</label>
                <select name="badge" class="badge empty">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Badge</option>
                    <option value="7.50">A</option>
                    <option value="8.00">B</option>
                    <option value="10.00">C</option>
                </select>
                - $ <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="price">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowvalidate">
            <th>2</th>
            <td>
                <label for="bfname2">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" id="bfname2" name="firstname2" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="bsname2">Lastname</label>
                <input type="text" id="bsname2" name="surname2" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="borank2">Officer Rank</label>
                <input type="text" id="borank2" name="officerrank2" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td class="form-element">
                <label for="badge">Choose a Badge Type (A, B, or C)</label>
                <select name="badge" class="badge empty">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Badge</option>
                    <option value="7.50">A</option>
                    <option value="8.00">B</option>
                    <option value="10.00">C</option>
                </select>
                - $ <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="price">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowvalidate">
            <th>3</th>
            <td>
                <label for="bfname3">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" id="bfname3" name="firstname3" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="bsname3">Lastname</label>
                <input type="text" id="bsname3" name="surname3" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="borank3">Officer Rank</label>
                <input type="text" id="borank3" name="officerrank3" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td class="form-element">
                <label for="badge">Choose a Badge Type (A, B, or C)</label>
                <select name="badge" class="badge empty">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Badge</option>
                    <option value="7.50">A</option>
                    <option value="8.00">B</option>
                    <option value="10.00">C</option>
                </select>
                - $ <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="price">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowvalidate">
            <th>4</th>
            <td>
                <label for="bfname4">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" id="bfname4" name="firstname4" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="bsname4">Lastname</label>
                <input type="text" id="bsname4" name="surname4" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="borank4">Officer Rank</label>
                <input type="text" id="borank4" name="officerrank4" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td class="form-element">
                <label for="badge">Choose a Badge Type (A, B, or C)</label>
                <select name="badge" class="badge empty">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Badge</option>
                    <option value="7.50">A</option>
                    <option value="8.00">B</option>
                    <option value="10.00">C</option>
                </select>
                - $ <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="price">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowvalidate">
            <th>5</th>
            <td>
                <label for="bfname5">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" id="bfname5" name="firstname5" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="bsname5">Lastname</label>
                <input type="text" id="bsname5" name="surname5" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="borank5">Officer Rank</label>
                <input type="text" id="borank5" name="officerrank5" class="empty">
            </td>
            <td class="form-element">
                <label for="badge3">Choose a Badge Type (A, B, or C)</label>
                <select name="badge" class="badge empty">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Badge</option>
                    <option value="7.50">A</option>
                    <option value="8.00">B</option>
                    <option value="10.00">C</option>
                </select>
                - $ <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="price">
            </td>
    </table>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Now that the HTML is done, let's see the Javascript, and explains each step of the logic.

```
const rows = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("rowvalidate"))
        
        rows.forEach(row => {
          let rowFields = Array.from(row.children)
          for (let i = 1; i < rowFields.length; i++) {
            rowFields[i].addEventListener("input", () => {
              let rowInput = rowFields[i].children[1]
              let valueFields = rowInput.value
        
              if(valueFields != "") {
                console.log(`This field is not empty anymore`)
                rowInput.classList.add("not-empty")
                rowInput.classList.remove("empty")
              } else {
                console.log(`This field is now empty`)
                rowInput.classList.remove("not-empty")
                rowInput.classList.add("empty")
              }
        
             for(let i = 1; i < rowFields.length; i++) {
                let isEmpty = true
                let input = rowFields[i].children[1]
        
                if(input.classList.contains("empty") === true) {
                  isEmpty = true
                } else {
                  isEmpty = false
                }
        
                if(isEmpty) {
                  console.log("Something is still empty.") 
                } else {
                  // No more empty fields, as all is not empty.
                }
             }
            })
          }
        })
```

Let's dive down into this code, and understand what I made (I'm pretty sure the logic could be a little bit straight, but I'm tired, if anyone want to correct)

Here, we are turning into an Array our list of rows to go through, simple as that, because `getElementsByCLassName` returns something similar to an Array: `HTMLCollection`. To keep it simple, it's like an array, but without some interesting property and method that only apply to array.

```
const rows = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("rowvalidate"))
```

We're using `forEach`, which is why we needed this to be an Array to use it on. `forEach` will apply everything inside of it to every element of that Array.
We name each element of that array `row` here.

```
rows.forEach(row => {
}
```

That `for loop` is quite simple. We do not wanna go over the `index[0]` for a simple reason, the `index[0]` is not a `<td>`, so we just omit him by starting to `i = 1`.
We'll first do a simple thing: listen to the input of each of our field by adding an `addEventListener` to each of them, and declaring some variables that will benefit us that I'll explain below.

```
for (let i = 1; i < rowFields.length; i++) {
    rowFields[i].addEventListener("input", () => {
      let rowInput = rowFields[i].children[1]
      let valueFields = rowInput.value
})
```

Don't freak out at those two `let`. They are simple.
We set `rowInput` to `rowFields[i].children[1]`, but why? Because, remember, each `rowFields` entry are a `<td>`, that himself contains an input! And the input on all of your `<td>` is the second element, so, are located to `index[1]`. So, we just access the children of our `<td>` and access the `index[1]` of it, to get our little desired input in that variable.

Then, what we will need of that input? We'll need his `value`, so we'll store it on `valueFields` simply by using of the `.value` property of input.

```
  let rowInput = rowFields[i].children[1]
  let valueFields = rowInput.value
```

Right, we have a lot of elements to work with now:
`rowInput` that contains the element Input for each of our `<td>`
`valueFields` that contains the value of each of that Input.
Let's work a logic out with those pieces of information!

Let's get deeper into that `if statement`...

```
 if(valueFields != "") {
        console.log(`This field is not empty anymore`)
        rowInput.classList.add("not-empty")
        rowInput.classList.remove("empty")
      } else {
        console.log(`This field is now empty`)
        rowInput.classList.remove("not-empty")
        rowInput.classList.add("empty")
      }
```

If the `valueFields` is `!=` (not) `""`, we'll add a class `not-empty` to that input, and remove, if he has, the `empty` class out of it. Those classes will makes it easier for us to retrieve who's empty, and who's not.
We do the opposite if the field becomes empty, we set `empty`, and remove `not-empty`. That simple.

Great, now you'll get what we'll do right?
We'll just start a new `for loop`, but this time, we will do a few more things:
Let's first check the piece of data we want to store.

```
let isEmpty = true
let input = rowFields[i].children[1]
```

We want to know if an input is empty within our `row` right, so let's just iterate through our list of fields in our row by looping through `rowFields`.
Now, we'll also do a `isEmpty` variable that will be `true` by default, but will changes once we verify each input.

`input = rowFields[i].children[1]` is the same trick we used above to get the `input` out of our `<td>` to manipulates it, simply.

Now, the logic is simple.

```
if(input.classList.contains("empty") === true) {
  isEmpty = true
} else {
  isEmpty = false
}

if(isEmpty) {
  console.log("Something is still empty.") 
} else {
  // No more empty fields, as all is not empty.
}
```

We are simply checking each input list of class via `classList.contains`, which returns `true` if it contains the desired class, or `false` if not.
If it contains the `empty` class, then our `input` is empty: we just set `isEmpty` to true, and if it is not containing it, then our input is not empty, we set `isEmpty` to false.

Then, it's your turn to play, in the case that `isEmpty` is true, do the desired actions (as they'll not be all not empty!), or if `isEmpty` is false, then all of our fields are completed, do what you want.

Hopefully it was clear enough, do not hesitate to comment!

Comment: If you felt this was useful and you got everything (the code works, you just have to do your actions into the last if), please set it as the answer. Else, please ask your questions over this comment.